# Overloaded Operator < to compare strings, sort linked list using string.compare?

Tags: c++, string, class, linked-list, operator-overloading

If anything in this code looks weird (like the illogical use of pointers) it's because it's for an assignment, so no need to let me know that there's absolutely no reason to use pointers in this situation. Thank you for you help in advance.

The code works for me except one thing, the insertNode function uses an overloaded < from the Pet class. this operator is supposed to compare the strings using the string.compare() function and return true or false based on the resulting value. However no sorting is done at all and the input file is just read in normally from beginning to end.

The problem is in the snippet below

```
bool  Pet::operator <(Pet &right)
{
    if (name.compare(right.name) < 0)
        return true;
    else if (name.compare(right.name) > 0)
        return false;
}
```

It seems to me that there is nothing wrong with this that would cause nothing to be changed. I haven't been able to test if the operators are right (> 0 and < 0) but i'm more concerned that it is doing nothing at all.

Comment: Finding the right section of your code and the right amount to post is sometimes hard but your question is really a bit too long imo.

Comment: You're much better off to only include what you think is specifically relevant to your problem. If people looking over your question need more information, they'll say so and you can add it. By adding everything here, regardless of it's importance, the question is too long to read in detail and most readers will pretty much just skip over the vast majority of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your comparison function doesn't handle the case when the strings are equal.

```
bool  Pet::operator <(Pet &right)
{
    if (name.compare(right.name) < 0)
        return true;
    else if (name.compare(right.name) > 0)
        return false;
}
```

`string.compare` returns a negative value if it's less then it's argument, 0 when they are equal and a positive value when it's bigger. You don't handle the case when it returns 0 and it therefore falls off the end of the function which is undefined behavior.

Change the `else if` to:

```
else if (name.compare(right.name) >= 0)
```

---

@Benjamin is right, your whole function could be shortened down to:

```
bool  Pet::operator <(Pet &right)
{
    return name.compare(right.name) < 0
}
```

I somehow always oversee these things when answering questions...

Comment: Or you could drop the if/else entirely and simply `return name.compare(right.name) < 0;` -- Or better yet, `return name < right.name;`

Comment: @BenjaminLindley added to my answer. Somehow I tend to oversee them when answering questions... dunno why.